# Android super user access in app to run commands

Tags: android, root

I want to run tap cmd like over 100 times and by using code below it will call su everytime and delay taps. So is it possible to request su when app first starts then run many commands fast? thanks!

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
    String cmd = "/system/bin/input tap 350 370\n";
    os.writeBytes(cmd);
    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    process.waitFor();

     } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself after you've removed the "*/".

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
    String cmd = "input tap 350 370";
    out.write(cmd.getBytes());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    process.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
```

It worked for me